# How to make sure a link in the spam-post won't get benefit in search-engine result

Tags: seo, search-engine, robots.txt

I have a wiki website. Many spammers using it for seo. They are adding spam-posts with a link to an external website. Is there way to make sure they won't get benefit of it? My thought is adding a text file like robots.txt to inform the search engine "don't consider external website links for search results". I don't want to prevent spammers from creating posts for the sake of advertisements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add rel="nofollow" to the links when you output them on your site.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569

They will still spam your site with links, so you'll need to monitor as well.